# Chrome extension that auto pins newly open tabs in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would like to write an extension that when I right click on a link and I select "open link in a new tab" that the newly open tab is automatically pinned.

I have been searching for the relevant code in the google.chrome api but I am having some problems.

Would you please help with my first plug-in?

Comment: Pretty sure you wouldn't be able to do this using the API (at least not without massive hacks) as it's the sort of thing malware would very easily exploit. Why do you want to this anyway?

Comment: I prefer to keep my tabs pinned, saves screen space and time.

Comment: You dont have to use right click at the top of the bar.